# Software license validation

Tags: java

I am working on a software license related task , the current validation method requires an online check, against the company server  , but since the users can manipulate there system clocks and continue using the software in offline mode , i have been assigned to look for a way to do offline validation clock checks using java , I know there are no bullet proof ways to do this but can anyone please suggest a way to make it hard using an expired license in offline mode . thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have the software know the earliest possible date (based on when that version went into production). If the clock is prior to that date, deny access until the online check succeeds. This requires storing this additional state (that the app is locked out) somewhere on the filesystem. You will probably want to have the app be "locked" if the file is missing to prevent someone from resetting the state simply by removing the file.

Also, when the license check succeeds (either online or offline), note the time. Deny any future access that is prior to that time and deny access until the online check succeeds. This forces time to march forward and if they mess up with their clock re-setting then they are locked out until they succeed with an online check.

When the license check succeeds online, store the server timestamp on the client (the timestamp that is used above to keep time moving forward).

Obviously, you will want to protect the contents of the file that persists this state, e.g., using encryption.

This is not fool-proof, but makes it harder for someone to use expired licenses by twiddling the clock.